# Events not adding to FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm implementing a calendar with a series of open time slots.

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

I am able to filter this calendar by time slot duration (15 min, 30 min, etc.) and by specific individuals' availabilities, but this only works when you select *one* individual:

```
<label> Filter by Person: </label>
<select id="PersonFilter">
     option value="none" selected="selected">None</option>
     @foreach (var person in ViewBag.People)
     {
        <option value="@item.PersonId">@person.FirstName,  @person.LastName</option>
     }
</select>
```

```
$('#PersonFilter').on('change', function(){    
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Sample/FilterCalendar",
        data: {
            "PersonId": $('#PersonFilter').val(),
            "AppointmentDuration": $('#AppointmentDuration').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
                var newEvents = [];        
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $.each(data, function(index){
                        newEvents.push({
                            'title': 'Open Slot',
                            'start': data[index].startTime,
                            'end': data[index].endTime,,
                            'color': 'green',
                            'allDay' : false
                        });
                    });
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newEvents);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            }              
        });
});
```

However, I want to be able to select multiple individuals' availabilities to view in the calendar, so I've implemented this selectpicker class into my select element (#PersonFilter) where you can select more than one person:

```
<label> Filter by Person: </label>
<select id="PersonFilter" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
     option value="none" selected="selected">None</option>
     @foreach (var person in ViewBag.People)
     {
        <option value="@item.PersonId">@person.FirstName,  @person.LastName</option>
     }
</select>
```

And this javascript:

```
$('#PersonFilter').on('change', function(){    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    var newEvents = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ($('#PersonFilter').val()).length; i++){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Sample/FilterCalendar",
            data: {
                "PersonId": ($('#PersonFilter').val())[i],
                "AppointmentDuration": $('#AppointmentDuration').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(index){
                    newEvents.push({
                        'title': 'Open Slot',
                        'start': data[index].startTime,
                        'end': data[index].endTime,
                        'color': 'green',
                        'allDay' : false
                    });
                });
            }              
        });
    }   
    console.log(newEvents)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newEvents);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
});
```

Which will log an array of the correct events to the console ([picture of new events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATa5t.png)), but will not repopulate the calendar -- no events appear at all. Anyone know why this is? Also, does anyone know how to remove duplicate events in FullCalendar? I understand that I get double the events if I select multiple people who are available at the same time.

In the working code (selecting only *one* person's availability to filter by), when I console log the new events it gives me a similar result: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARBIA.png), so I'm unsure why it won't populate the calendar in this new code.

Comment: What this code will do is repeatedly, and concurrently, try to download a filtered set of events for each person selected in the dropdown. That doesn't really make any sense and it's very inefficient. Instead, refactor your client and server-side code so you can send all the selected people as a list within _one_ AJAX request, and get a single set of results back

Comment: Meanwhile the main reason you're not getting _any_ results is because you've moved `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newEvents);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` ouside the "success" function of the AJAX. Since AJAX requests are _asynchronous_, that code will now run _before_ your AJAX request has finished and the events have been downloaded. However, the solution is not as simple as moving it back inside the success - as I said, you're going to trigger multiple competing requests and the results would just keep overwriting each other.